# Applying Sobel operator in numpy to simple binary image

Tags: python, numpy, sobel

I'm trying to apply the Sobel operator to a simple binary image, but the resulting gradient is flipped (when comparing to the output of scipy's `signal.convolve2d` function.

```py
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def sobelx_homemade(arr, kx):
    offset = 1
    sx = np.zeros(arr.shape)
    for y in range(offset, arr.shape[0] - offset):
        for x in range(offset, arr.shape[1] - offset):
            rstart, rend = y-offset, y+offset+1
            cstart, cend = x-offset, x+offset+1
            w = arr[rstart:rend, cstart:cend]
            Ix = kx * w
            sx[y, x] = Ix.sum()
    return sx

A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


kx = np.array([
    [-1, 0, 1],
    [-2, 0, 2],
    [-1, 0, 1]
], dtype=np.float)

ky = np.array([
    [1, 2, 1], 
    [0, 0, 0], 
    [-1, -2, -1]
], dtype = np.float)

Gx = signal.convolve2d(A, kx, boundary='symm', mode='same')
Gy = signal.convolve2d(A, ky, boundary='symm', mode='same')

# calculate homemade sobel x gradient
myGx = sobelx_homemade(A, kx)

plt.subplot(131)
plt.title("Original")
plt.imshow(A, cmap="gray")
plt.subplot(132)
plt.title("Gx")
plt.imshow(Gx, cmap="gray")
plt.subplot(133)
plt.title("My Gx")
plt.imshow(myGx, cmap="gray")
```

[image: output of script, gx and my gx should match]

I expect the images labeled "Gx" and "My Gx" to be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that a **true** convolution flips the kernel/filter matrix, which explains the flipped result.

This video from Andrew Ng, explains the differences between textbook convolution and cross-correlation commonly used in machine learning style image processing:
https://youtu.be/tQYZaDn_kSg?t=308